# HTTP Error 403.1 with WCF service on IIS

Tags: wcf, http, iis-6, http-status-code-403

I have added an WCF REST endpoint with WebHttpBinding to our existing ASP.NET server hosted on IIS 6. When I make a GET request such as http://{server}/cmis.svc/object/{object_id}, the object is returned by the server. But when I make a DELETE request to the *same URL*, IIS returns 403.1 error (Forbidden: Execute access is denied). I tried setting the *Write* permission on the Home Directory tab of the website but that didn't help. As you can see from the URL, cmis.svc is at the root of the website.

Any guesses what might be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: In your Request Filtering on your site are you disallowing the DELETE verb?

Comment: @Richard Blewett - That did the trick. I had to modify properties for .SVC extension and add DELETE to 'limit verbs to' configuration. Thanks! _Now how do I mark your comment as the answer?_ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Request Filtering on the site to allow the DELETE verb